# Trying to create a text input with an attached button

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a textbox with an attached button that looks similar to a Kendo DatePicker or NumericTextBox. This is close, but it doesn't quite line up. Any help straightening this up would be appreciated.

```
<style>
    .unselectable
    {
        -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
</style>

<span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header" style="width: 136px">
    <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
    <input class="k-input" type="text" name="searchParam" id="searchParam" placeholder="Name ..." />
        <span class="unselectable k-button k-select">
            <img class="unselectable" src="~/Images/search_flashlight_16.png" />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything you should need is this:
See [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TmgPs/2/)

```
<span class="k-textbox k-button k-space-right">
    <input value="This is the value" />
    <a class="k-icon k-filter"></a>
</span>
```

Also see the "documentation" (Look at the source for the example) for this [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/styling/index.html).

**EDIT:**
Since the asker really wanted it to behave as a button (i.e. the click-effect), just add the k-button class to the outter span.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that section in the documentation. This is almost perfect. I really want it to behave like a button. If you click this, it doesn't change color like a button.

Comment: So close. When you click on the text, the button clicks also.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but I felt like [Shion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16536864/1920035) wasn't quite what I was looking for. So after a bit of experimenting I came up with this which doesn't give you the flicker of the button:

```
<span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
  <input style="width: 100%;" type="text" class="k-input">
  <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select" role="button">
    <span class="k-icon k-i-filter"></span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Live Example: [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OGocInEj)